# View with Text inside overflowing Link component in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I've read a ton of discussion of the similar topic, but none of them seem to work in my case, maybe because it's inside a Link, I dont know.

Here's the return of my component named NoteCard:

```
<View style={styles.outterCard}>
  <Link
    href={{
      pathname: "/note/[id]",
      params: { id: id },
    }}
    style={styles.link}
  >
    <View
      style={styles.innerview}
    >
      <Text style={styles.noteTitle} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="tail">{note.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.noteContent} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail">{note.content}</Text>
    </View>
  </Link>
</View>
```

And here are the styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  outterCard: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    width: "50%",
    paddingHorizontal: 4,
    paddingVertical: 4,
  },
  link: {
    backgroundColor: "rgb(41,42,43)",
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    width: "100%",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  innerview: {
    width: "100%",
    flex: 1,
    flexShrink: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'red',
  },
  noteTitle: {
    color: "rgb(225,190,220)",
  },
  noteContent: {
    color: "rgb(160,160,160)",
    width: "100%",
    flex: 1,
    flexShrink: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'blue',
  },
});
```

[image: See how even the 'innerview' is overflowing the Link]

I dont know if this is relevant, but this NoteCard is rendered in a flatList like this:

```
  <FlatList
    data={notes}
    numColumns={2}
    keyExtractor={(note) => note.id}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <NoteCard id={item.id} />
    )}
    style={styles.flatList}
    columnWrapperStyle={styles.columnWrapper}
    contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
  />
```

styles:

```
  flatList: {
    width: '100%',
    padding: 4,
    paddingTop: 50,
  },
  columnWrapper: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  contentContainer: {

  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer. The Link component from expo-router actually  behaves as a Text component. The solution is to give it a prop called 'asChild' and it will pass its parameters to the first child component, as it is stated in the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/router/navigating-pages/):

> The Link component wraps the children in a  component by
> default, this is useful for accessibility but not always desired. You
> can customize the component by passing the asChild prop, which will
> forward all props to the first child of the Link component. The child
> component must support the onPress and onClick props, href and role
> will also be passed down.

And so I used Pressable, from react-native:

```
<View style={styles.outterCard}>
      <Link
        href={{
          pathname: "/note/[id]",
          params: { id: id },
        }}
        style={styles.link}
        asChild
      >
        <Pressable
          style={styles.innerview}
        >
          <Text style={styles.noteTitle} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="tail">{note.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.noteContent} numberOfLines={2} ellipsizeMode="tail">{note.content}</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </Link>
    </View>
```